# Inherited razor page OnPostAsync - Multiple handlers matched

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-routing, asp.net-core-3.1

I have encountered an issue with my new test project when I inherit a razor page from another.
So I had an editor page and I wanted to use the same flow just with gave an extra param (id), the code was:

```
public class EditModel : BaseModel
{
    public EditModel() 
    {
    }

    public Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class CreateModel : EditModel
{
    public CreateModel()
    {

    }

    public Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also I defined the editor cshtml as:

```
@page "{id:int}"
...
```

and the create cshtml as:

```
@page
...
```

I would expect that the routing was obvious cuz editor's parameter is NOT optional, but create does not need a parameter, but I got the error:

> Multiple handlers matched

If I define parameter in create page model too it starts working with 0 value.

I have two questions about that:

**Can I define a routing template where I can explicitly forbid the parameter (and how) to avoid ambiguity?** (Now I'm using default routing template.)

**Shoud I avoid this kind of inheritance of razor pages?** I can except that if it is by design and use another way to do it.

I would like to mention that I know I can define another handler methods different from default onget/onpost/etc and use it this way, however I think the above problem should work properly if I can define the routing in a good way.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to the board! Before digging more about your purposes for this design, let first make something clear about the scenario.

- You are probably using ASP.NET Core Razor Page, but you ended up with this line `EditModel : BaseModel` so I assume that there must be something like `BaseModel : PageModel`
- Next thing I know that you make another inheritance which is `CreateModel : EditModel` and this time it bugged me out because this obviously will make EditModel inherit a method so-called `Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id)` because that what inheritance do!

**For example:**

```
public class Test1
{
    public void sayHello(){
        Console.WriteLine("hehe");
    }
}

public class Test2 : Test1
{
    public void sayHello(string inputValue){
        Console.WriteLine(inputValue);
    }
}
```

and the result when you have something like

```
Test2 test = new Test2();
test.sayHello();
test.sayHello("something");
```

The result would be

```
hehe
something
```

Once again, I'm not sure about your purposes on this methodology, so it would be nice if you can share some though so we both can evolve in something new.

**UPDATE:**
At this point, I understand that you created a problem for a case study. So let see if I came up with something right.

.NET core allows you to define some specific route inside `Startup.cs` beside the default routing, which obviously won't fit in this case.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/edit", "{handler?}/{id?}");
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/create", "{handler?}");
        });
}
```

Now, I believe if you put `@page "{id:int}"` in your `.cshtml` page, it would run as expected.

Comment: Your example is very good cuz - I think - the pagemodel inheritance should work like the same. So if we stay with your example the current behaviour is when you call `test.sayHello();` you get the error _Multiple handlers matched_. That is happening when I call the Post method.

Edit: Thats why I think there is something wrong with routing, cuz I expect the same as in your example!

Comment: I have just updated my answer, please have a look. I hope this helps :), and `Happy New Year` btw.

Comment: Thank you for taking care and happy new year to you too! 
I'm not happy with that but I have to say your solution gives the same result:
`InvalidOperationException: Multiple handlers matched. The following handlers matched route data and had all constraints satisfied: System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] OnPostAsync(), System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] OnPostAsync(Int32)`